# Can d3.js circle's radius be specified by a style attribute?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

This [**explainer**](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/styles-in-d3js.html) shows how d3.js style attributes can be used to vary the appearance of a circle (fillcolor, stroke-color, stroke-width, etc).

Can I set the radius of a d3.js circle using a style attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set radius of circle as attribute OR style.

But, if you specify an `attr("r")`, but you have a css style such as `circle
{r: 50;}`, the style-sheet always takes priority over the
attributes.

However, if you switch to using `style("r")`, then the
element-specific style takes priority because it is more specific, as
you would expect.

So you can use these based on the precedence.

```js
//circle 1
d3.select("svg")
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 50)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("r", 10); // Radius 10 as attribute

//circle 2
d3.select("svg")
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 150)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .style("r", 10); //Radius 10 as inline style
```

```css
/*External styles*/

circle {
  fill: green;
  r: 50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height=500 width=500></svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

yes you can. But its better to use `attr` for `DOM value manipulations` and `style` for `css`.

```
             svg.selectAll(".dot")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "dot")
                .style("r", 3)
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                  return x(d.date);
                }
                )
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                  return y(d.value);
                })
                .attr("stroke", function(d) {
                  return color(this.parentNode.__data__.name)
                })
                .attr("fill", function(d) {
                  return color(this.parentNode.__data__.name)
                })
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/pngebo3e/12/) using `style` and [example](https://jsfiddle.net/pngebo3e/) using `attr` though both work just same way but have a look at the `structure of DOM`.

Using `attr`:

```
`<circle class="dot" r="3" cx="0" cy="174.375" stroke="#1f77b4" fill="#1f77b4"></circle>`
```

Using `style`:

```
`<circle class="dot" cx="0" cy="174.375" stroke="#1f77b4" fill="#1f77b4" style="r: 3;"></circle>`
```